# Problem with connecting (ssh) to an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, yaml, git-bash

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  
  VPCCIDR:
   Type: String
   Default: 10.1.0.0/16
  
  PrivateSubnetCIDR:
   Type: String
   Default: 10.1.1.0/24

  PublicSubnetCIDR:
   Type: String
   Default: 10.1.2.0/24
  

Resources:

  VPC:
   Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
   Properties:
     CidrBlock: !Ref VPCCIDR
     Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: VPC

  PrivateSubnet:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
   Properties: 
     CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnetCIDR
     VpcId:  !Ref VPC
     Tags: 
       - Key: Name
         Value: PrivateSubnet     

  PublicSubnet:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
   Properties: 
     CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnetCIDR
     VpcId:  !Ref VPC
     Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: PublicSubnet         

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: InternetGateway       

  GatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties: 
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicRouteTable:
   Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
   Properties: 
     VpcId: !Ref VPC
     Tags: 
       - Key: Name
         Value: PublicRouteTable   

  Route:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Route
   Properties: 
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable               

  PublicRouteAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet       
  
  NatSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: 'Nat Security Group'
      GroupName: NatSecurityGroup
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
       - CidrIp: !Ref PrivateSubnetCIDR
         Description: 'Private Subnet traffic'
         FromPort: -1
         ToPort: -1
         IpProtocol: -1  
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: NatSecurityGroup

  NatInstance:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
   Properties: 
     ImageId: ami-003acd4f8da7e06f9
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     KeyName: marjan
     SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
     SecurityGroupIds:
       - !Ref NatSecurityGroup
     SourceDestCheck: false
     Tags: 
       - Key: Name
         Value: NatInstance    

  EIP:
   Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
   Properties: 
     InstanceId: !Ref NatInstance
     Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: EIP       

  PrivateRouteTable:
   Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
   Properties: 
       VpcId: !Ref VPC
       Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: PrivateRouteTable   

  NATRoute:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Route
   Properties: 
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      InstanceId: !Ref NatInstance
      RouteTableId: !Ref  PrivateRouteTable     

  PrivateRouteAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet     
  
  JumpBoxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: 'JumpBox Security Group'
      GroupName: JumpBoxSG
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
       - CidrIp: 62.162.179.210/32
         Description: 'SSH'
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         IpProtocol: tcp 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: JumpBoxSecurityGroup 


  JumpBoxEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
      ImageId: ami-08e4e35cccc6189f4
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
       - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
         DeviceIndex: "0"  ### dodeluva public ip adressa na prviot interface
         SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
         GroupSet:
           - !Ref JumpBoxSecurityGroup
      KeyName: marjan
      Tags: 
         - Key: Name
           Value: JumpBoxEC2Instance 


# Do tuka mrezhen del
  
  PublicEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: 'EC2Public'
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
       - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
         Description: 'http'
         FromPort: 80
         ToPort: 80
         IpProtocol: tcp
       - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref JumpBoxSecurityGroup
         Description: 'ssh Jumpbox'
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         IpProtocol: tcp
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: PublicEC2SecurityGroup



  PublicEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
     ImageId: ami-0022f774911c1d690
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     NetworkInterfaces:
       - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
         DeviceIndex: "0"
         SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
         GroupSet:
           - !Ref PublicEC2SecurityGroup
     KeyName: marjan
     Tags: 
       - Key: Name
         Value: PublicEC2Instance

   
  PrivateEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: 'EC2Public'
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
       - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref PublicEC2SecurityGroup
         Description: 'MySQL From Public EC2'
         FromPort: 3306
         ToPort: 3306
         IpProtocol: tcp
       - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref JumpBoxSecurityGroup
         Description: 'SSH From JumpBox'
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         IpProtocol: tcp
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: PrivateEC2SecurityGroup


  PrivateEC2tInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
     ImageId: ami-0022f774911c1d690
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
     KeyName: marjan
     SecurityGroupIds:
       - !Ref PrivateEC2SecurityGroup
     Tags: 
       - Key: Name
         Value: PrivateEC2tInstance
```

Here is my code, i am having trouble connecting to the jumpbox instance, the instance is running but when i try to connect with it it gives me " connect to host 54.145.162.171 port 22: Connection timed out " [image]

I am using the commands on the screentshot , ihave no idea what's causing this problem, i cannot ssh to anything. if anyone has an idea how to solve this or has a few methods on solving this please let me know.

Comment: Check security groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine except that you **constrained** your `JumpBoxEC2Instance` to be accessed only from `62.162.179.210/32`. This is probably not your real address, even if you may think it is. If you double check your IP, or change the SG as shown below, it should work:

```
  JumpBoxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: 'JumpBox Security Group'
      GroupName: JumpBoxSG
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
       - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
         Description: 'SSH'
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         IpProtocol: tcp 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
         - Key: Name
           Value: JumpBoxSecurityGroup
```